# Default shell zsh but responding bin/bash

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell, zsh

I have no idea what I did! I was installing maven and one of the guides had me do something and now I'm stuck in default zsh. I've tried changing my terminal preferences to be /bin/bash, as well as my user preference through general Apple System Settings.
However, I still get

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
```

When I try ECHO $SHELL, I get

```
/bin/bash
```

I'm definitely in the wrong place as I was able to return mvn -v with a version and now it's saying mvn isn't found.

Comment: That message indicates you *are* running bash (it's trying to talk you into switching to zsh). Specifically, you're running the built-in version, which is rather old; it may be you were using a newer version before (maybe installed with homebrew or something like that), in which case you probably want to find that version and switch from /bin/bash (the built-in one) to it.

Answer (score 0):

I gather that you're running a Mac, since Apple made zsh their default shell starting with the macOS 10.15 "Catalina" release back in 2019.

You can relaunch a bash interactive login shell with this command, to see if that helps, assuming that you normally use bash.

```
exec bash -il
```

Your bash config files may have been modified by whatever you did, so try examining these files, if they exist, to see if anything looks odd.

- `.bashrc`
- `.bash_profile`
- `.bash_login`
- `.profile`

If you're using a Mac, [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) is a really nice package manager that lets you just type `brew install maven`.

Also, if you changed your shell to zsh, and want to switch back to bash:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```